# TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from a MySQL table.

My code

```
def getData(self, ID):
    #Load data from MySQL
query = 'SELECT * FROM goals WHERE ID = "%s"'% (ID)
        try :
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            conn.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
            data = False

        if data is not False:
            for row in data:
                self.ID = row[0]
                self.description = row[1]
                self.imageID = row[2]
                self.imageLink = row[3]
                self.Location = row[4]
                self.status = row[5]
                self.publishID = row[6]
                self.goardID = row[7]
                self.LikesID = row[8]
                self.createdDate = row[9]
                self.createdTime = row[10]
                self.hide = row[11]
x  = newThink()
print x.create_New()
print x.goalID, x.subscriptionID, x.LikesID, x.goardID
see = x.addData('Just the Second', 'Nairobi', 89900845,'http://image.com/789900845')
print see

see = x.postData()
print see

see = x.getData(x.goalID)
print see


print "Now here is the formatted data../n"
print '........'
print x.description, x.Location, x.imageID, x.imageLink
```

The error :
    TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

This is the error I keep getting. It returns a tuple I guess so Im not so sure

Comment: Which line raises the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate where the error occurs.  But I can make a guess:

```
data = cursor.fetchone()
....
for row in data:
    self.ID = row[0]
    ...
```

`data` is a tuple, the values from one `row`.  `for row in data` iterates on that tuple, so that `row` will be individual fields.  The error indicates that one of other those `row` is a number, a `long`.

If you used `data = cursor.fetchall()`, then there would be multiple `rows` data, and the rest would probably work.

Alternatively stick with `fetchone` and skip the `for row in data` loop.  Just use `data[0]`, etc.

In sum, make sure you understand the structure of `data`.  It might not be the list (or other iterable) of tuples that your code assumes.